# convert single dimensional array into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I need to convert single dimension array into multidimension array in php 
and also need to convert this index array into associative array.

```
[0] => 9
[1] => Bang Bhasm
[2] => 123
[3] => 161
[4] => 6
[5] => Sales
[6] => Cash
[7] => Sales-GST @12%
[8] => Output CGST @6%
[9] => 10
[10] => Be Fresh Churan
[11] => 123
[12] => 154
[13] => 6
[14] => Sales
[15] => Cash
[16] => Sales-GST @12%
[17] => Output CGST @6%
```

**And I want this expected Output:-**

```
 [0] Array (
        [0] => 9 
        [1] => Bang Bhasm 
        [2] => 123 
        [3] => 161 
        [4] => 6 
        [5] => Sales 
        [6] => Cash 
        [7] => Sales-GST @12% 
        [8] => Output CGST @6% 
        [9] => 10 
        )
[1] Array( 
        [10] => Be Fresh Churan
        [11] => 123 
        [12] => 154
        [13] => 6 
        [14] => Sales 
        [15] => Cash 
        [16] => Sales-GST @12% 
        [17] => Output CGST @6%
        ) I
```

Comment: What have you tried? what is your expected output?

Comment: I want this array in this format                                                                          [0] Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => Bang Bhasm
    [2] => 123
    [3] => 161
    [4] => 6
    [5] => Sales
    [6] => Cash
    [7] => Sales-GST @12%
    [8] => Output CGST @6%
    [9] => 10
)               [1]     Array(   [10] => Be Fresh Churan
    [11] => 123
    [12] => 154
    [13] => 6
    [14] => Sales
    [15] => Cash
    [16] => Sales-GST @12%
    [17] => Output CGST @6%) I want array in this format

Comment: Can you also add your desired Array format in your question so that all can have better understanding?

Comment: `array_chunk($arr, 9);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every array in php is an associative array. If the keys are not defined, then php automatically converts the array into an indexed array.

You might want this:

```php
$single_dimension_array = array(9, 'Bang Bhasm', 123, 161, 6, 'Sales', 'Cash', 'Sales-GST @12%', 'Output CGST @6%', 10, 'Be Fresh Churan', 123, 154, 6, 'Sales', 'Cash', 'Sales-GST @12%', 'Output CGST @6%');
```

Or this

```php
$multi_dimension_array = array(
                    array(9, 'Bang Bhasm', 123, 161, 6, 'Sales', 'Cash', 'Sales-GST @12%', 'Output CGST @6%'),
                    array(10, 'Be Fresh Churan', 123, 154, 6, 'Sales', 'Cash', 'Sales-GST @12%', 'Output CGST @6%'));
```

This would be helpful: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-arrays/